# Set background color of UITableView programmatically not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have added a UIView using storyboard and subclassing it. Within this view, I am adding a UITableView programmatically. Here is the code to create the tableview and add it:

```
private func commonInit() {
    self.backgroundColor = .clear

    self.categoryTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height))

    categoryTableView?.delegate = self
    categoryTableView?.dataSource = self

    self.categoryTableView?.backgroundView = nil
    self.categoryTableView?.backgroundColor = .yellow

    self.categoryTableView?.isScrollEnabled = false
    self.categoryTableView?.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    self.addSubview(categoryTableView!)
}
```

This is what it looks like. I'm expecting the background of the tableview to be yellow (it is white in the screenshot)
[image]

I have also set the cells background color to clear which seems to be working. When I look at the UI hierarchy, it is pretty obvious that the White is coming from the the tableview.

[image]

I feel like this should be really strait forward. The strange part is the lines `self.categoryTableView?.isScrollEnabled = false` and `self.categoryTableView?.allowsMultipleSelection = true` both seem to be working, but the background color changing isn't.

Comment: Set the background color in main thread.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh Yep that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got the exactly same problem and found that just changing the `tableView.backgroundColor` after `tableView.backgroundView = nil` doesn't work.

My case also was a programmatically created `UITableView` inside an `UIView`.

The solution is to add a `backgroundView` to `tableView` and change the property `backgroundColor` of `backgroundView` object.

---

### **Swift 5 / iOS 12.x**

**Changing tableView background color**

For any color other than `.clear`, the above should work:

```
    self.tableView.backgroundView = UIView() //Create a backgroundView
    self.tableView.backgroundView!.backgroundColor = .lightGray //choose your background color
```

**Changing tableViewCells background color**

Going a little further, some may find that the tableView background color didn't appear as intended because of the background colors of the `UITableViewCell` instances. A simple solution to make sure the cells have a transparent background:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
```

Comment: To make it work with `.clear` define your background view as `UIView(frame: .infinite)`

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in a playground, and the result was as expected.

```
import UIKit
import XCTest
import PlaygroundSupport


let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

let tableView = UITableView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
view.addSubview(tableView)
```

The result:

[image: colored tableview]

My guess is something else is afoot here.  Maybe something with the sizing of the frames, or where you are calling the `commonInit()` method?

Comment: `commonInit()` is called from `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`. I think this might be part of the issue since setting the background color in the main thread (like @Badhan Ganesh suggested) seemed to have solved the problem. Maybe calling functions from `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` makes it run on a thread other than the UI thread.